# How should I initialize the Context to accessing remote GlassFish server?

Tags: java, glassfish, jndi

I am using a GlassFish-4.0 in my subnet (192.168.1.115:3700). I have already deployed an enterprise application including an EJB, in which I defined some business methods. Now I would like to remotely access the EJB from my Java application client.

I am trying something like this:

```
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.115");
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
GreetingService bean = (GreetingService) ctx.lookup(GreetingService.JNDI_NAME);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.1.115; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:392)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1205)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:393)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at hu.igergo.java.dummy.client.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Kapcsolat elutasítva
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Kapcsolat elutasítva
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:329)
    ... 15 more
Exception in thread main javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'greeting' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.1.115; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at hu.igergo.java.dummy.client.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.1.115; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:334)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.1.115; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:392)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1205)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:393)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Kapcsolat elutasítva
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Kapcsolat elutasítva
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:329)
    ... 15 more
```

I only configured ORB / IIOP (127.0.0.1). I didn't change anything on the default JNDI settings. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVmt6.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Configurations/server-config/ORB/IIOP Listeners/orb-listener-1` settings the "*Network Address*" field must be the real subnet IP address. (E.g. in my problem: 192.168.1.115)